# Issues with word2vec

Tags: python, nltk

I'm wondering why this program only creates a py plot of letters rather than words. Am I giving it the wrong kind of data for word2vec? The program runs just fine if I use

```
sentences = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'for', 'word2vec'],
            ['this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'sentence'],
            ['yet', 'another', 'sentence'],
            ['one', 'more', 'sentence'],
            ['and', 'the', 'final', 'sentence']]
# train model
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

this instead of the text document for my data.

```
import string
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from matplotlib import pyplot

filename =  'book.txt'
file = open(filename, 'rt')
text = file.read()
file.close()

words1 = list(text.split())
words1 = [word.lower() for word in words1]

table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
removepunct = [w.translate(table) for w in words1]
print(removepunct[:100])



# train model
model = Word2Vec(removepunct, min_count=1)
# fit a 2D PCA model to the vectors
X = model.wv[model.wv.key_to_index]


pca = PCA(n_components=2)
result = pca.fit_transform(X)
# create a scatter plot of the projection
pyplot.scatter(result[:, 0], result[:, 1])
words = list(model.wv.key_to_index)
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    pyplot.annotate(word, xy=(result[i, 0], result[i, 1]))
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that removepunct is not a list of lists of tokens.
If removepunct is a list of token, then each character in a token will be considered as a token by gensim's Word2Vec model.

Comment: Interesting, so I have a tokenized list of words. Would I just need to make each word its own list? Would that still work the same as the other example I gave since the other example has each sentence as it's own entity in a larger list.

Comment: @code, if you turn your text into a list of one-word "sentences", they won't make for very interesting vectors...

Answer (score 0):

Your successful example is a list of sentences, i.e. a list of lists of words.  The second time, you pass it a list of strings and Python, in its usual Python fashion, iterates over the strings one letter at a time instead of iterating over lists of words.

The nltk provides high-level methods to digest a text file into a list of sentences. Here is a foolproof way to get tokenized sentences:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(".", ["book.txt"])

model = Word2Vec(corpus.sents(), min_count=1)
# Continue as before
```

If you want to remove punctuation, you must do it after the input has been parsed into sentences (since punctuation matters), like this:

```
clean_sents = [ [w for w in s if w.isalnum()] for s in corpus.sents() ]
```